# symfony2: fosuserBundle -> determine roles when registering users

Tags: symfony, registration, roles, fosuserbundle

i am starting with symfony2 and fosUserBundle, and I get the following problem:
i have 2 kinds of users in my application (let say recruiters and job seekers. The recuiters can post job offers, and the job seekers can apply to them).

If a new recruiter wants to create an account, he clicks on "create my recruiter account", 
If a job seeker wants to create an account, he clicks on "create my job seeker account"

thus, I need to grant roles during registration, according to what the user is.

for now, i created 2 routes:
 - fosuserbundle_recruiters (/register/recruiters) 
 - fosuserbundle_jobSeekers (/register/jobseekers).

These 2 routes leads to the same action: the registerAction in the fosUserBundle registration controller.
In this action, i get the route name "$routeName = $request->get('_route');", and according to that $routeName i grant "$user->addRole('ROLE_RECRUITER');" or "$user->addRole('ROLE_JOBSEEKER');"

Is this a secure way to do this? I don't know how to handle this, I spent my whole day on that and can't find in the documentation or in the forums...
Any help, tip or hint would soooo much appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to ***override the fosUserBundle registration controller***.
and create custom registration function in your user controller

Comment: hello @Nisam, thanks a lot for your answere.

Just to make sure I undestand well: i should override the fosUserBundle, and then to create 2 differents actions (1 for each role) in this overriden Bundle?

And only because I'm curious :) : do you know if my method can be a breach in my security?

thanks for your time

Comment: you can create separate functions for each. later you may can extend your unique registration logic with same code

Comment: OK it s clear now. I ll create 2 actions where i will give the right role(s), and inside those actions call to a same registration function.
Thanks Nisam